# How to wrap image title text into div and show this block on hover?

Tags: jquery

I made such a markup:

```
<div class="packery-image-wrapper col-md-4 item animated fadeInRight">
    <a href="/">
        <img class="someClass" title="flat" src="http://here.com/img" alt="flat" width="629" height="800">
    </a> 
</div>
```

Styles:

```
.packery-image-wrapper{
    ...
   position: relative;
   ...
}  
.packery-image-wrapper .caption{
    ...
    position: absolute;
    ... etc.
}
```

And i want get title from the image and make a tooltip with it using such a code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".packery-image-wrapper").on("mouseenter",function () {
   var captionContent = $(this).find('a img').attr("title");
   $(captionContent).wrap('<div class="caption"></div>').appendTo('.packery-image-wrapper a').show();
   }).on("mouseleave", function () {
       $(".caption").hide();
});
```

});

Here I can get image title and i can output it into console, but then nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are passing the title to `jQuery()` method, since it is not starting with `<` it will be considered as a selector so, `$(captionContent)` will not return any element. Instead you need to create a div and set `captionContent` as its text

```js
$(".packery-image-wrapper").on("mouseenter", function() {
  var $caption = $(this).find(".caption");
  if (!$caption.length) {
    var captionContent = $(this).find('a img').attr("title");
    $('<div class="caption"></div>').html(captionContent).appendTo($(this).find('a'))
  }
  $caption.show();
}).on("mouseleave", function() {
  $(this).find(".caption").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="packery-image-wrapper col-md-4 item animated fadeInRight">
  <a href="/">
    <img class="someClass" title="flat" src="//placehold.it/64" alt="flat" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Yep, just spotted this issue when putting it in a jsfiddle... Have deleted incorrect answer (despite upvote) :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie also we need to check whether already a caption is added, if so there is no need to do it again

Comment: Indeed... was re-writing the whole thing when your answer pinged up :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7e04x31m/).

```
$(".someClass").on('mouseover', function(e){
    if($(".customTitle").length)
        $(this).parent().siblings('.customTitle').show();
    else {
        $(this).parent().after($('<div />', { text: $(this).attr('title'), class: 'customTitle', 
                                             css: { top: $(this).parent().offset().top - 100, 
                                                   left: $(this).parent().offset().left} }));
    }
}).on('mouseout',function(e){
    $(this).parent().siblings('.customTitle').remove();
});
```